# What is breaking the tooltips in this Quarto dashboard?

Tags: r, quarto, sparklines, reactable

I have some `sparklines` embedded in html tables in my reports.  I have been experimenting with using Quarto dashboards now for my reports.  However, the width of the sparkline tooltip text blows up to the entire width of the page.

I made a reproducible example with code from the `reactable` documentation:
https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html

Here is a snapshot and then the code.

`reactable` allows me to specify a css style for columns.  Is there any css that could fix this?  Or any additional specification to `sparkline()`?

[image]

````
---
title: tooltip test
format: dashboard
editor: source
---

```{r}
#| warning: false
#| message: false
library(reactable)
library(sparkline)
library(dplyr)
library(tippy)
```

```{r}
data <- chickwts %>%
  group_by(feed) %>%
  summarise(weight = list(weight)) %>%
  mutate(boxplot = NA, sparkline = NA)

reactable(
  data, 
  columns = list(
    weight = colDef(
      header = tippy("weight", "test tooltip"),
      cell = function(values) {
        sparkline(values, type = "bar", chartRangeMin = 0, chartRangeMax = max(chickwts$weight))
      }
    ),
    boxplot = colDef(
      header = tippy("box", "test tooltip"),
      cell = function(value, index) {
        sparkline(data$weight[[index]], type = "box")
      }
    ),
    sparkline = colDef(
      header = tippy("line", "test tooltip"),
      cell = function(value, index) {
        sparkline(data$weight[[index]])
      }
    )
  )
)
```
````

Comment: Seems to be specific to `format: dashboard` (works fine in e.g. html and revealjs formats)

Comment: Tobo - thanks for taking a look.  That's my observation as well.  I think the sparkline is inheriting some css from the dashboard container that breaks it?  I don't know how to read or debug the raw html.

Comment: `sparkline` has optional arguments for tooltipContainer and tooltipClassname. 
 Is there any way to use this to control the class and style? 
 https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-docs

Comment: I believe this is the class that should be assigned to the sparkline object (in case this helps with the solution) "jqstooltip"

Comment: I wish I could contribute but I don't have the skills! Is it worth asking [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `.jqstooltip` class in css to change the `max-width` of your background tooltip like this:

````
---
title: tooltip test
format: dashboard
editor: source
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}
.jqstooltip { 
 min-width: 0px !important; 
 max-width: max-content !important; 
}
```

```{r}
#| warning: false
#| message: false
library(reactable)
library(sparkline)
library(dplyr)
library(tippy)
```

```{r}
data <- chickwts %>%
  group_by(feed) %>%
  summarise(weight = list(weight)) %>%
  mutate(boxplot = NA, sparkline = NA)

reactable(
  data, 
  columns = list(
    weight = colDef(
      header = tippy("weight", "test tooltip"),
      cell = function(values) {
        sparkline(values, type = "bar", chartRangeMin = 0, chartRangeMax = max(chickwts$weight))
      }
    ),
    boxplot = colDef(
      header = tippy("box", "test tooltip"),
      cell = function(value, index) {
        sparkline(data$weight[[index]], type = "box")
      }
    ),
    sparkline = colDef(
      header = tippy("line", "test tooltip"),
      cell = function(value, index) {
        sparkline(data$weight[[index]])
      }
    )
  )
)
```
````

Output:

[image]